# return a std::Vector<object> from function needs a default value

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a function which is like this

```
static int locationinfo( const char *pszSrcFilename 
                       , const char  *pszLocX 
                       , const char *pszLocY
                       , const char *Srsofpoints=NULL
                       , std::vector<PixelData>& results=std::vector<PixelData> 
                       /* char **papszOpenOptions = NULL,int nOverview = -1,*/  
                       )
{
--filling results 
return 1;


}
```

I want to return `results` from above function. I used `&` but compiler needs a default value for `results`, how can I define a default value for `std::vector<PixelData>` in function definition?

here is my error

```
error: default argument missing for parameter 5 of ‘int locationinfo(const char*, const char*, const char*, const char*, std::vector<PixelData>&)’
 static int locationinfo(const char *pszSrcFilename , const char  *pszLocX ,const char *pszLocY,const char *Srsofpoints=NULL
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

thanks

Comment: non-`const` references can't bind to temporaries. Did you try passing it by `const` reference?  In addition to you not constructing a default `std::vector`, which would be `std::vector<PixelData>()`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius So can I modify and add objects to vector if I use const?

Comment: @MajidHojati  _"So can I modify and add objects to vector if I use const?"_ No, you cannot. What about moving the `results` parameter before `Srsofpoints` and get rid of the need for a default value?

Comment: @MajidHojati No, you can't. What would be the point of adding elements to such temporary?

Comment: "I want to return results" If that function is supposed to fill a vector and return it, why don't you actually create the vector in the function and return it? Do you have to append elements?

Comment: @user0042 wow, thanks it was my mistake

Comment: @Bob__ no I just need to fill it, but I want to report the status from function using an int value

Comment: @MajidHojati So I posted that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply reorder your parameters to get rid of the need for a `const` reference and default parameter declaration:

```
static int locationinfo( const char *pszSrcFilename 
                       , const char  *pszLocX 
                       , const char *pszLocY
                       , std::vector<PixelData>& results // <<<<
                       , const char *Srsofpoints=NULL    // <<<<
                       /* char **papszOpenOptions = NULL,int nOverview = -1,*/  
                       )
{ 
   // ...
}
```

---

If you however need a function that only takes the 1st three parameters you can use a simple overload additionally:

```
static int locationinfo( const char *pszSrcFilename 
                       , const char  *pszLocX 
                       , const char *pszLocY
                       ) { 
   std::vector<PixelData> dummy;
   return locationinfo(pszSrcFilename,pszLocX,pszLocY,dummy);
}
```